# Creating Character Variables with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose we have the following data.table:

```
x_dt <- data.table(sexn = c(1, 0, 0, 1, NA, 1, NA), 
                   country = c("CHN", "JPN", "BGR",  "AUT", " ", "TWN", " "), 
                   age = c(35, NA, 40, NA, 70, 18, 36)
)
```

I am trying to create a variable asia_region, which has a value of 1 when country `%chin% c("CHN", "JPN", "KOR",  "SGP", "TWN")`, a value of `0` when country is not missing and NA when country is missing.

The following code populates 0's when country is missing.

```
result <- x_dt[, asia_region := ifelse(country %chin% c("CHN", "JPN", "KOR",  "SGP", "TWN"),1 , 0)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can directly coerce the logical to binary with `as.integer` or `+`, then change the values to `NA` where the 'country' is blank (`""`) by specifying a logical condition in `i` and assignment (`:=`) for those corresponding elements in 'asia_region' to `NA`

```
x_dt[,  asia_region := +(country %chin% c("CHN", "JPN", "KOR", "SGP", "TWN"))]
x_dt[trimws(country) == "", asia_region := NA_integer_]
```

-output

```
> x_dt
   sexn country age asia_region
1:    1     CHN  35           1
2:    0     JPN  NA           1
3:    0     BGR  40           0
4:    1     AUT  NA           0
5:   NA          70          NA
6:    1     TWN  18           1
7:   NA          36          NA
```

---

Or if we need a `ifelse/fifelse` (`if/else` wouldn't work as it is not vectorized i.e. it expects input expression with length 1 and not more than that)

```
x_dt[, asia_region := fifelse(trimws(country) == "", NA_integer_,
        fifelse(country %chin% c("CHN", "JPN", "KOR", "SGP", "TWN"), 1, 0))]
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Is there a more intuitive solution using "if", "else if", "else" statements?

Comment: I suggest that akrun's first solution is more canonical and efficient from a `data.table` point of view. `if` is certainly not right, `ifelse`/`fifelse` are certainly good alternatives. (I suggest you accept this answer as-is, it is unlikely a better solution can/will be offered, imo.)

Comment: The second solution, which uses fifelse does not require chaining expressions. Doesn't this make it more efficient than the first one?

Comment: @MKro No, it wouldn't.  I think the first one is more direct as it is just a coersion

Answer (score 0):

How about a `dplyr()` solution? I'd make a vector of the countries, for easier referencing:

```
asia_countries <-  c("CHN", "JPN", "KOR",  "SGP", "TWN")

x_dt |>
  dplyr::mutate(asia_region = ifelse(country %in% asia_countries, 1, 0)) |>
  dplyr::mutate(asia_region = ifelse(country == " ", NA, asia_region))
```